# How to undo pretty print on chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

After clicking on pretty print, the button disappears and I can't undo it, not even after refreshing the page. I need to undo because i'd like to edit the code and that doesn't work when pretty print is active.
How do i do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Chrome will create new file with name "file_name:formatted" and open new tab. You only need close this file :D. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Double-click the name of the source file in the sources pane, and it gets reloaded in the editor un-prettified.